# What am i doing wrong with my scope calculation function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-management, linked-list

I i have this assignment and i just dont know what to do right now it does not give the the scope i need for every like 3 points its gives me some huge number.

here is the assignment

> Write a program that accepts a polygon with n vertices, and calculates its perimeter.
> To perform the task against, two new types are required:
>
> - The point structure contains the fields:
>   Two integers indicating a reference point (coordinate) in the plane.
> - The polygon structure contains the fields:
>   A pointer to an array of type point, the size of the array, and the perimeter of the polygon.
>
> A structure of type must be declared at the beginning of the program
> polygon, and make an input of n points.
>
> There is no need to sort the points, it will be assumed that order
> The reception of the points is continuously, so that between every 2
> adjacent points there is a side belonging to the polygon.
>
> Below is the list of functions required to perform the task:
>
> 1. scanPoint
> 2. createPolygon
> 3. distance
> 4. calculateScope
> 5. addPoint
> 6. removePoint
> 7. freeMemory
>
> Note: it must be assumed that the perimeter of a polygon with less than 3 vertices is equal to 0
>
> ```
>   typedef struct point
>   {
>       int x, y;
>    }point;
>    
>    typedef struct polygon
>    {
>       int n;
>       point* points;
>       double scope;
>    }polygon;
> ```

and here is the code i tried to make

```
int main()
{
    int i, n, idx=0;
    polygon* poly;
    printf("Start Program\n");
    poly = createPolygon();
    printf("How many points to add: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Point #%d: \n", i + 1);
        addPoint(poly);
    }
    printf("Output: Scope of polygon: %.2lf\n", poly->scope);
}


void scanPoint(point* p)
{
    printf("\nplease enter x and y data by order-> ");
    scanf_s("%d%d", &p->x,&p->y);   
}
double distance(point* pA,point*pB)
{
    int x = (pA->x) - (pB->x);
    int y = (pA->y) - (pB->y);
    double d = 0;
    d = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
    return d;
}
polygon* createPolygon()
{
    
    polygon* New=(polygon*)malloc(sizeof(polygon));
    if (New == NULL)
    {
        printf("the alocation failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("the alocation sucsess");
        New->n = 0;
        New->scope = 0;
        New->points = NULL;
        return New;
    }

}



double calculateScope(point* arr, int n)
{
    double d = 0;
    polygon* prev = arr;
    prev->points=(point*)malloc(sizeof(point));
    assert(prev);
    prev = &prev->points[n-1];
    if (n == 0) return d;
    d = distance(prev, arr);    
    return d;

}


int addPoint(polygon* poly)
{
    polygon* ptr = poly;
    ptr->points = (point*)realloc(ptr->points, (ptr->n + 1)*sizeof(point));
    if (ptr == NULL)return 0;
    scanPoint(ptr->points);
    ptr->scope+=calculateScope(ptr->points,ptr->n);
    ptr->n++;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why return an error code that you're not going to check?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: first call to `calculateScope`, `ptr->n` equals 0, so `prev->points[n-1];` is `points[-1]` .. whoops, out of bounds, undefined behavior. I think you want to pass `ptr->n+1` there or do `ptr->n++` before calling that. Also highly recommend using a debugger to step thru your code. If you don't know how to use one, now is an excellent opportunity to learn.